# Creating new data frame in function in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I've been trying to write a function which creates new object based on the previous one (after few changes). However, I didn't manage to do it.
Here's my data frame:

```
 Names <- c("Tom", "Alex", "James", "John", "Wayne", "Harry") 
 a <- c(1,3,6,8, NA, 5) 
 b <- c(3,6,9,1, NA,1)  
 c <- c(7,3,1,6,NA,6) 
 d <- c(1,4,7,2,NA,8) 
 data <- data.frame(Names,a,b,c,d)
```

And here's my function

```
NAvalues <- function(x,object, y){
    object[sample(seq_len(nrow(object)), x, replace = FALSE),-1] <- NA   
    summary(object)   
    y <- data.frame(object) 
}
```

The first part works fine, but I'm struggling to create a new object, which would have a name specified by y.

```
NAvalues(2, data, new)
```

When I use this, I get an error that there is no such an object as `new`.
Can someone tell me why is it so?

Comment: Because there is no object named 'new'.  You create an object named 'y' inside of your function but 'y' goes away at the end of the function anyways.  Why not just get rid of the 'y' parameter but return the created data.frame from inside the function and then assign the output of the function to what you want it called? So you would use the function like... `new <- NAvalues(2, data)`

Comment: That was really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Just to expand @Dason's comment: Perhaps you're thinking along the lines of passing `new` "by reference" (as you could/would do in e.g. C++). That's not how R works. You will have to assign the output of an R function (the `return` argument) to a new variable.

Comment: @kubafrustrat I updated my answer with the solution

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, the objective of your task is to create a data.frame named as defined by the argument `y` by executing the function `NAvalues()`.

```
NAvalues <- function(x,object, y){
        object[sample(seq_len(nrow(object)), x, replace = FALSE),-1] <- NA   
        summary(object)
        assign(paste(y), data.frame(object), envir = .GlobalEnv)
} 

NAvalues(x = 2, object = data, y = "new")  #y must be a character because it is the name of the new data.frame
```

The key of the solution is

```
assign(paste(y), data.frame(object), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

which allows to create a variable named as the `string` `parameter` `y` and assign that variable to the `global.environment`

Comment: `y = new` is still redundant. Just delete the `y` variable from the function call, and use it with `new <- NAvalues(x = 2, object = data)`.

Comment: @LAP you are right, however, I was answering to the question of @kubafrustrat. Furthermore, I have the impression he wanted to use the function `NAvalues()` to create a `data.frame` in the `global.environment` as `side-effect`.

Comment: If so, you'd need to specify `y <<- data.frame(object)` and the `return(y)` would be redundant. Right now no dataframe is created within the `.globalEnv`. Still, it would be better to assign the new object manually with `new <- NAvalues(...)`.